# Can I transfer a domain name before expiration to save money?

Tags: hosting, domain-name

I purchased a domain name and hosting package from weebly.com, for a year. Now I realize that it cost me almost double the amount a domain goes for at a site like whois.com.

Is it possible to transfer my domain name registration from weebly to whois.com to save money?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the subscription agreement with a particular provider, and should be  easily answered by reading the subscription contract with said provider.

Answer (score 2):

Transferring your domain to another registrar will not get you any money back from your existing one. As part of the transfer you will have to renew your domain with the new registrar for at least a year (sometimes two depending on the domain). This gets added on to the remaining term that you purchased via your previous registrar.

So, transferring will incur some more up-front cost if you've only just registered the domain.

Comment: I am not sure in which case you would have to "renew your domain with the new registrar" but I just did a transfer myself and the transfer fee also covered the renew fee (for 1 year) with the new registrar. So yes, it saves money. In my case it saved $10, instead of renewing with Godaddy, I transferred mine to NameCheap. My first domain transfer though, I am not sure about your case.